# show scanning folders that are being scanned by glob() in php

Tags: php

For a simple file search..i wrote code using glob() function. Well, its working fine and perfect. But while glob() is searching for file in directories and sub-directories..it should display a line something like **scanning c:\wamp\www\xyz** directories like that..showing what are the folders its scanning currently(my requirement)..i searched stackoverflow and php.net for solution..but of no use..i know its sounds weird which is not supported by glob() for now..but seeking for some alternative solutions or suggestions from experienced people. Pls review my code once and suggest me a solution if its known..

```
         $dir='c:\wamp\www\apps';
         $strsear='add';
         function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) 
         {
           $globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*$strsear*.$ext");
           print_r($globFiles);
           $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
           foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
                recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);
            }
           foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$v) {
                echo "$v"; echo "<br/>";
            }
          }
         recursiveGlob($dir, 'php');
```

Comment: Maybe you could call your php-script with an Ajax-call. In your php-script, turn output-buffering off and flush every time the directory changes. Then with javascript, show the returned directories.

Comment: @Michel thanks for quick reply. I am not aware of output buffering completely..but if we turn off output buffering then ob_flush() wont work right? correct me if iam wrong..

Comment: That's right. You can also call `ob_start()` at the start of your script and `flush();ob_flush();` after changing directories, it has the same effect. (Note that this will not work on some servers.)

Comment: @Michel ok thanks for your proper guidance :). I will try that n get back to u.

Comment: @Michel Your suggestion is perfectly right..when directory changes i can able to print directory..but can you guide for ajax calling..i never used ajax for now..if its possible kindly help for ajax call..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had a little snippet somewhere, maybe it's a nice example

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head>
<script>
var hsys;
function call_ajax(){
    hsys=false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        hsys=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{hsys=new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');}
        catch(e){try{hsys=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}
        catch(e){}}}
    if(!hsys){ajax_error(pag);return false;}
    hsys.open('POST',"pag1.php",true);
    hsys.onreadystatechange=resp_ht;
    hsys.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/html');
    hsys.send();
    }  

function resp_ht(){
    if(hsys.readyState==4){
        if(hsys.status==200){
        alert('FINISHED');
        return false;
        }
    }
    var rs=hsys.responseText;
    document.getElementById('test_ajax').innerHTML=rs;
}
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="test_ajax" style="border:1px solid black;padding: 10px;"><b>Nothing here at the moment</b></div><br>

<div onclick="call_ajax()"><b>[START REQUEST]</b></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

And **pag1.php**

```
<?php 
session_write_close();
while(ob_get_level()>0)ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
for($i=1;$i<15;++$i){

echo 'Hello, I am number '.$i."<br />\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_clean();
sleep(1);
}
```

P.S. This is plain javascript. jQuery might be usefull.